# Read values from localized file iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, localizable.strings

I have created a localized string file which contains Error message in Key/Value Pair. What I just want to read values on key basis just like Plist.

Here is content of my Localized file

```
"SERVICE_ERROR" = "Some error occurred while processing your request, Please try later";
```

And this is how I am saving this string in user preferences

```
[ErrorManager setLastErrorInPreferences:NSLocalizedString(@"SERVICE_ERROR", nil)];
```

Here is setLastErrorInPreferences method

```
+ (void)setLastErrorInPreferences:(id)errorString {
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSString *errorStringWithTime = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"On %@:\n%@", now, errorString];
    [prefs setObject:errorStringWithTime forKey:KlastError];
}
```

But its not working. Its just saving the key as it is. Its not reflecting the value of this key in user preferences.Kindly let me know what I am missing.

Comment: is there only single line in your localized file, please check that you entered last semicolon as well as `"key"="value";` format for all the keys. The error that you shown commonly appears due to invalid localized file. So check it again

Comment: no there are many other strings as well. I've checked it.All lines have ; at  the end of string.

Comment: @aqsaarshad Show your `setLastErrorInPreferences` and your class `ErrorManager`. Also make sure the name of the file should be `Localizable.strings`

Comment: @Rajan its working fine now. My bad. i was using a customized name rather than default "Localizable.string" name.

Comment: Thankyou so much :) appreciated (Y)

Comment: Apart from it not working, saving localised strings in your user defaults is a bad idea. Consider what happens if a user launches your app in French, you store a French error message, and then the user launches the app again in Italian. Or you stored a French error message, the user updates the app which fixes spelling errors in your French localisable strings, but the user will have the wrongly spelled message forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you  have a **Localizable.strings** file. No other name will work.
Change the content of your localizable file from

```
"SERVICE_ERROR" = "Some error occurred while processing your request, Please try later";
```

to

```
SERVICE_ERROR = "Some error occurred while processing your request, Please try later";
```

(Remove "" from your key SERVICE_ERROR and keep a semi-colon at the end **;**)

Also show what your `setLastErrorInPreferences` is doing?

Usage

```
NSString* error = NSLocalizedString(@"SERVICE_ERROR", nil);   
NSLog(@"%@",error);
```

It worked fine.

My File

[image]

**EDIT**

Fetching the errorValue. Make some method in your `ErrorManager` class and fetch it from there as `kLastError` won't be available in your Controller class.

```
NSString* yourError = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:KlastError];
```

Comment: I've tried without quotation marks still its not working.

Comment: @aqsaarshad show your `setLastErrorInPreferences` code

Comment: + (void)setLastErrorInPreferences:(id)errorString {
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSString *errorStringWithTime = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"On %@:\n%@", now, errorString];
    [prefs setObject:errorStringWithTime forKey:KlastError];
}

Comment: @aqsaarshad Show your `ErrorManager` class too. Edit in question

Comment: @aqsaarshad Its working, you need to fetch the value also from your `NSUserDefaults` key too. Check edit

Comment: @aqsaarshad If it works for you, Kindly accept as a tick.

Comment: i am already fetching it in another class where i'm showing it to user.

Comment: @aqsaarshad if my answer helped me, please accept as a tick